# How to access the image chosen by PictureService in Gluon on IOS as a file

Tags: ios, gluon, gluon-mobile

I am trying to find to attach a picture as a file and send it via the Gluon application. On using the PictureService from Gluon plugin I am able to get the Image object with the following code.

```
  Services.get(PicturesService.class).ifPresent(service -> {
  service.loadImageFromGallery().ifPresent(image -> setImage(image));
  });
```

How do I get the actual location of the image file on IOS or atleast can I convert the Image to a temp file to send it.

Referred this link [SwingFXUtils shows NoClassFoundError](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42032859/swingfxutils-shows-noclassfounderror), does not work for me as I am not using takePicture

Comment: Did you see this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47569927/sharing-multiple-files-with-gluon-shareservice-image-and-txt)? I think you want exactly the same, don't you?

Comment: Yes, it worked thanks !